# Product Variation Checkbox

Tags: commerce

I have a product with two variations.  Shoppers can choose different sizes (paying more for larger sizes) and they can also choose whether to add a carrying case or not.

The different sizes are implemented as a select list.  No problem there.  The carrying case option is boolean.  I want to represent it as a checkbox (like Ubercart can) but can only get it to show as a single radio button and, of course, when you have a single radio button, once it's been turned on, it cannot be turned off.

Under 'Attribute Field Settings', the 'Attribute selection widget' only allows for 'Select list' or 'Radio buttons'.  Is there a way to represent it as checkbox?  Or, what is the best way to handle binary (On/Off) product variations?

Comment: The reason it is either a select or radio is because only one value is acceptable. So really what you need to do is allow more then one. Can you explain how to implemented the `carrying case option` a bit more?

Comment: For example, if the product is a laptop, the customer may or may not want to purchase a carrying case with it.  If he wants the carrying case, he would be able to select it with a checkbox and deselect it if he changes his mind.  With the radio button, once it's been selected, it stays that way.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need the same thing...

Comment: I did but can't remember how and the site has since been refreshed by someone else so I can't refer to it.  I am currently working on a module for D8 Commerce 2 that does the same thing but it's very alpha.  https://github.com/creativepragmatic/commerce_product_options